# Add Default Value to every column MySQL strict mode

Tags: mysql

I cannot disable MySQL strict mode, so i need to add default values to every column for table.

I'm attempting below:

```
ALTER TABLE media
CHANGE upload_date upload_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CHANGE title title VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT '',
CHANGE slug slug VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT '',
CHANGE meta_title meta_title VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT '',
CHANGE meta_desc meta_desc VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT '',
CHANGE meta_keys meta_keys VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT '',
CHANGE filename filename VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT '',
CHANGE filetype filetype VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT ''
```

I'm getting the error **SQL Error (1366): Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x81\xDB\x8C\xD9\x84...' for column 'meta_keys' at row 1**

How do i solve?

Comment: My guess is that the CHANGE is trying to alter the current charset used by that field; you may have respecify it so as to not inadvertantly change it to the server default.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you have to change the columns BEFORE you enable strict mode. Otherwise MySQL will give an error for any incorrect column values whenever you INSERT/UPDATE, or ALTER TABLE :(

Comment: Can you clarify what **exactly** needs to be changed?

Comment: Every column that isn't set explicitly in all INSERT/UPDATE queries *must* have a default column value (e.g. VARCHAR, CHAR need empty string '', integer types need '0', etc). Also, date/time columns can't have 'zero' values in them e.g. '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673938/php-script-to-fix-mysql-columns-to-work-with-strict-mode

Comment: And https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/18/upgrading-to-mysql-5-7-beware-of-the-new-strict-mode/

Comment: Please don't link to other external sites to explain your answer - they might change and leave your answer useless. Better edit the answer and add such explanation (including **what exactly needs to be changed** and how)

Comment: That’s in my first answer

Answer (score 0):

Check the `characterset` of the connection and client.

```
 - mysql -uroot -p
 - \s
```

You have to ensure that the client and connection characterset is exactly the same as that of Db.

[image: Connection Characterset]

If they are not, then use the following command to reset the connection & client characterset.

Use the following command to set correct charset and collation for the client to server connection

```
- mysql -uroot -p
- SET NAMES 'charset_name
- /execute/alter/table/query
```

Answer (score 0):

This note is a bit old. Following a sql query to generate some alter table to execute to set default value.

The script list all column without nullable status and without value. Primary key are also ignored.
We can improve listing on CASE part. For example I've missed some case with date.

```
SET @target_database="my_database";
SET @default_text="''";
SET @default_int="0";
SET @default_date="0000-00-00";

select table_schema as database_name,
       table_name,
       column_name,
       data_type,
       CONCAT(
        "ALTER TABLE ",table_schema,".",table_name," MODIFY COLUMN ",column_name," ",column_type," DEFAULT ", 
        CASE 
            when data_type like "%text" then @default_text
            when data_type like "varchar" then @default_text
            when data_type like "%blob" then @default_text
            when data_type like "%int%" then @default_int
        END
       ,";")
from information_schema.columns
where  
      column_default is null
      AND column_key <> "PRI"
      AND is_nullable = "NO"
     AND table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'sys','performance_schema','mysql')
      AND table_schema = @target_database
ORDER BY table_schema,
         table_name,
         ordinal_position;
```